# Approximations for finite n in limit-based definition of the exponential function

Tags: numerical-methods, asymptotics, exponential-function

The exponential function can be defined via:
$$
e^x = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \right)^{n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g(x; n)
$$

In my problem, I actually have the right hand side $g(x;n)$, for large ($O(100)$), but finite $n$, which I need to evaluate numerically.

Are there ways to derive the corrections due to finite $n$; i.e. an asymptotic expansion in $n$?

That way I can evaluate something like $g(x;n) \approx e^{x} c(x;n)$ pretty easily, assuming $c(x;n)$ is a polynomial or rational function or otherwise easy to evaluate.

Comment: That's an interesting question, but isn't $g(x,n)$ so much close to $\mathrm e^x$ for your $n$ that $c = 1$?

Comment: Out through $n=50$ $c$ only gets up to $\approx 0.9975$ and is converging to $1$ slowly -- I figure that with the asymptotic correction, I can achieve much better numerical results, with just a few computations.

Comment: Try Taylor series;  $$\begin{align} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n &= \exp\left\{n \log\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)\right\} \\ &= \exp\left\{n \left( \frac{x}{n} - \frac{x^2}{2n^2} + \cdots \right)\right\} \\ &= e^x \left( 1 - \frac{x^2}{2n} + \cdots \right) \end{align}$$  Just use more terms of the Taylor series to get more terms of the asymptotic.

Comment: @AntonioVargas there's something mis-typed in you comment, but that is basically the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @Dave, I don't see it.  Where's the typo?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I mis-interpreted something; your expression is correct.  However in my application I can leave the extra terms up in the exponential, $exp [ x -x^2/(2n) \ldots]=e^x exp[ -x^2/2n \ldots], not as a separate polynomial factor.

Comment: Great!  Hope it helps.